# forEach, for loop behaviour when index changed

Tags: javascript, loops, whatsapp, preload, tauri

I am trying to mask phonenumbers on whatsappweb with using preloading stuff, to achieve this I query child elements of parent and checking if it contain +90 or 0 and replace it by another text and remain same the ones have not +90 or 0

My initial code was:

```
let contactNames = document.querySelectorAll(".l7jjieqr,._11JPr");
let contactNamesLength = contactNames.length;
console.log(contactNamesLength)
for (let i = 0; i < contactNamesLength; i++) {
  const element = contactNames[i];
  element.title = "";
  if (element.textContent && element.innerText.includes("+90", 0) && !element.innerText.includes("REPLACEDTEXT")) {

    element.innerText = element.textContent.replace(
      /^[+]*[(]{0,1}[0-9]{1,4}[)]{0,1}[-\s\./0-9]*/g,
      "REPLACEDTEXT"
    );

    if (element.parentNode.className == "_3q9s6") {
      element.innerText = element.textContent.replace(
        /^[+]*[(]{0,1}[0-9]{1,4}[)]{0,1}[-\s\./0-9]*/g,
        "REPLACEDTEXT"
      );
    }
    // changing group name on chatlist to Xx
    if (element.parentNode.className == "Hy9nV") {
      element.innerText = element.textContent.replace(
        /^[+]*[(]{0,1}[0-9]{1,4}[)]{0,1}[-\s\./0-9]*/g,
        "REPLACEDTEXT"
      );
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is:

The index(i) is changing when we scroll on whatsappweb and it replace the text even if it doesn't contain 0 or +90

My question is:

Is there a way that I can query those childs one by one individually even when new child added ?

What I tried ?

1 - I tried to use forEach instead for loop but result was same.

```
 contactNames.forEach(child => {
      // I tried to use forEach instead for loop but result was same.
      });
```

2 - Tried to use MutationObserver too but result was still same.

My posible questions to solve:

Can I re-render(refresh, reload) an element without refreshing whole page with javascript ?

Edit:

[image: The change in loop(i)]

Edit 2:

Here electron version,

https://github.com/amanharwara/altus

Here the preload script,

https://github.com/amanharwara/altus/blob/master/src/preload.js

You can fork this repo and test it with adding my code above.

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is *`index(i)` is changing* - what's `index(i)`?   I can say: javascript is single-threaded, so when your loop is running, the only thing that will change is what's is changed inside your loop.  If this is affecting `contactNamesLength` or `contactNames` then you need to handle that change.  One option might be to cancel the loop and restart it, another might be to use a `while` with the `length` recalculated inside the condition.  Without seeing the actual issue, `in action*`, it's only speculative.

Comment: It seems most likely from your code that `contactNames` is changing,  but you've not included how you get that and the code provided doesn't appear to change it.

Comment: Yes its affecting `contactNamesLength` I mean the "i" in loop with index. I will update this with a video or gif in action. Can you give me more detail of handling that change ?

Comment: `contactNamesLength` can't change *in the code provided*.  How/when is your code being called?  A video of the affect won't help; it (ideally) needs to be reproduceable with code in the question.  See [mcve].

Comment: It could be something specific to "whatsappweb".

Comment: `contactNamesLength` is changing because the function binded to scroll event. So thats why this loop is being executed everytime we scroll.

Comment: Just added an image of the change, basicly it happens when you scroll to see other childs of parent.